# Google Sheets, Lookup and SUM together all matching

Tags: google-sheets

What I am looking for is it to `LOOKUP("HP",X25:X37,W25:W37)`

Now that will output the highest value present within the range, but my intended goal is for it to find how many times it can find "HP" then Sum together all those values within the range where HP is next to it

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L2KQweIOsS3IRjSADDeQhmK4QEy01ccmjSFe2gkQkFM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: so you wana sum 5+10 in W column if X column is HP?

Comment: Thats pretty much it, but I need it to go down the whole column cause HP can appear on any line that a choice is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY({W25:X37}, "select sum(Col1) where Col2='"&N12&"' label sum(Col1)''")
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, that does exactly what i need it to! Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to get this to check if no output is given and output 0?

Comment: `=IFERROR(QUERY({W25:X37}, "select sum(Col1) where Col2='"&N12&"' label sum(Col1)''"),0)`